# Converting a double to a string for a radio button

Tags: java, android, string, double

I have not been able to figure out but what im trying to do is convert a couple double variables in my application to a string. Im not exactly sure how to do that in my current code. I keep getting a "cannot invoke isChecked() on the primitive type double". I wasnt able to find any tutorial explaining how to do this so forgive me. Here is my code, any tips would be appreciated :

```
package net.androidbootcamp.zipcarrentalapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    private RadioGroup radioGroupId;
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    private Button button;
        final RadioButton Compact = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radCompact);
        final RadioButton MidSize = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radMidSize);
        final RadioButton Luxury = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radLuxury);
        final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        double radCompact = 59.99;
        double radMidSize = 65.99;
        double radLuxury = 89.99;
        int days = 0;
        double computeValue;

        public void operation(int days)
        {
            if(days <= 10)
            {
                if(radCompact.isChecked())
                {
                    computeValue = radCompact * days;
                    txtResult.setText("Cost:" + Double.toString(computeValue));

                }

                else if (radMidSize.isChecked())
                {
                    computeValue = radMidSize * days;
                    txtResult.setText("Cost: " + Double.toString(computeValue));
                }
                else if (radLuxury.isChecked())
                {
                    computeValue = radLuxury * days;
                    txtResult.setText("Cost:" + Double.toString(computeValue));
                }
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little bit off. You have three buttons,

```
final RadioButton Compact = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radCompact);
final RadioButton MidSize = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radMidSize);
final RadioButton Luxury = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radLuxury);
```

You call `isChecked()` on them. For example, this

```
if(radCompact.isChecked())
```

should be

```
if (Compact.isChecked())
```

and then

```
else if (MidSize.isChecked())
```

and finally

```
else if (Luxury.isChecked())
```

**Edit** And,

```
final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
```

should be

```
final TextView txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed it. I appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to typecast the variable to the Double object.

Something like:

```
((Double) computeValue).toString
```